# ffmpeg example progs fail on Ubuntu 18.04.5 but work on macOS 10.14.6

Tags: c, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04, macos-mojave

Am trying to build ffmpeg 4.3 example progs downloaded from git source on both Ubuntu 18.04.5 and macOS Mojave 10.14.6. All built correctly on both systems. Compiled progs work on macOS but fail on Ubuntu. For example:

On Ubuntu when I run the **muxing** program with very basic info I get this:

```
dev@boots:~/code/new_ffmpeg/FFmpeg-master/doc/examples$ ./muxing test.mp4
[mpeg4 @ 0x5626024f8b40] [IMGUTILS @ 0x7ffdd2893080] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[mpeg4 @ 0x5626024f8b40] Ignoring invalid width/height values
[mpeg4 @ 0x5626024f8b40] [IMGUTILS @ 0x7ffdd2893060] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[mpeg4 @ 0x5626024f8b40] The encoder timebase is not set.
Could not open video codec: Invalid argument
dev@boots:~/code/new_ffmpeg/FFmpeg-master/doc/examples$
```

But when I run the same on macOS I get this:

```
Kinley:examples CC15$ ./muxing test.mp4
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 352x288, q=2-31, 400 kb/s, 25 tbn
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s
pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:0 dts_time:0 duration:0 duration_time:0 stream_index:0
pts:-1024 pts_time:-0.02322 dts:-1024 dts_time:-0.02322 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
pts:512 pts_time:0.04 dts:512 dts_time:0.04 duration:0 duration_time:0 stream_index:0
pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:0 dts_time:0 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
pts:1024 pts_time:0.02322 dts:1024 dts_time:0.02322 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
pts:1024 pts_time:0.08 dts:1024 dts_time:0.08 duration:0 duration_time:0 stream_index:0
```

... many lines removed...

```
pts:127488 pts_time:9.96 dts:127488 dts_time:9.96 duration:0 duration_time:0 stream_index:0
pts:437248 pts_time:9.91492 dts:437248 dts_time:9.91492 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
pts:438272 pts_time:9.93814 dts:438272 dts_time:9.93814 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
pts:128000 pts_time:10 dts:128000 dts_time:10 duration:0 duration_time:0 stream_index:0
pts:439296 pts_time:9.96136 dts:439296 dts_time:9.96136 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
pts:440320 pts_time:9.98458 dts:440320 dts_time:9.98458 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
[aac @ 0x7f99d4009600] Qavg: 386.667
Kinley:examples CC15$
```

When I run the **remuxing** program on Ubuntu I get this:

```
dev@boots:~/code/new_ffmpeg/FFmpeg-master/doc/examples$ ./remuxing test1.mp4 gaga.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.51.101
  Duration: 00:00:30.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2468 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2392 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dev@boots:~/code/new_ffmpeg/FFmpeg-master/doc/examples$
```

When I run the same on macOS I get this:

```
Kinley:examples CT15$ ./remuxing test1.mp4 gaga.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4145 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4067 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Output #0, mp4, to 'gaga.mp4':
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 4067 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
in: pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:-2002 dts_time:-0.0667333 duration:1001 duration_time:0.0333667 stream_index:0
out: pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:-6006 dts_time:-0.0667333 duration:3003 duration_time:0.0333667 stream_index:0
in: pts:2002 pts_time:0.0667333 dts:-1001 dts_time:-0.0333667 duration:1001 duration_time:0.0333667 stream_index:0
out: pts:6006 pts_time:0.0667333 dts:-3003 dts_time:-0.0333667 duration:3003 duration_time:0.0333667 stream_index:0
in: pts:-1024 pts_time:-0.02322 dts:-1024 dts_time:-0.02322 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
out: pts:-1024 pts_time:-0.02322 dts:-1024 dts_time:-0.02322 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
in: pts:1001 pts_time:0.0333667 dts:0 dts_time:0 duration:1001 duration_time:0.0333667 stream_index:0
out: pts:3003 pts_time:0.0333667 dts:0 dts_time:0 duration:3003 duration_time:0.0333667 stream_index:0
in: pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:0 dts_time:0 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
```

...many lines removed... and last 10 lines:

```
in: pts:1347584 pts_time:30.5575 dts:1347584 dts_time:30.5575 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
out: pts:1347584 pts_time:30.5575 dts:1347584 dts_time:30.5575 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
in: pts:917917 pts_time:30.5972 dts:916916 dts_time:30.5639 duration:1001 duration_time:0.0333667 stream_index:0
out: pts:2753751 pts_time:30.5972 dts:2750748 dts_time:30.5639 duration:3003 duration_time:0.0333667 stream_index:0
in: pts:1348608 pts_time:30.5807 dts:1348608 dts_time:30.5807 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
out: pts:1348608 pts_time:30.5807 dts:1348608 dts_time:30.5807 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
in: pts:1349632 pts_time:30.6039 dts:1349632 dts_time:30.6039 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
out: pts:1349632 pts_time:30.6039 dts:1349632 dts_time:30.6039 duration:1024 duration_time:0.02322 stream_index:1
in: pts:1350656 pts_time:30.6271 dts:1350656 dts_time:30.6271 duration:1009 duration_time:0.0228798 stream_index:1
out: pts:1350656 pts_time:30.6271 dts:1350656 dts_time:30.6271 duration:1009 duration_time:0.0228798 stream_index:1
Kinley:examples CC15$
```

Why does this not run on Ubuntu 18.04.5 and work on the Mac?

The file test1.mp4 is a known good file and other progs such as VLC can correctly play on both systems.

Can anyone please provide any advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am unable to duplicate this issue. How did you configure ffmpeg?

Comment: @llogan I'm using this: https://forum.linuxconfig.org/t/install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux-linuxconfig-org/2005  <br> But I'm getting an error after it does the make install that is this:  <br> License: nonfree and unredistributable
...
GEN libavdevice/libavdevice.pc
./ffbuild/pkgconfig_generate.sh: 21: .: Can’t open libavfilter/libavfilter.version
ffbuild/library.mak:102: recipe for target ‘libavdevice/libavdevice.pc’ failed
make: *** [libavdevice/libavdevice.pc] Error 2
dev@boots:~/ffmpeg/ffmpeg$

Comment: Try following [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).